# Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of model

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, enums

I am having the following error when trying to execute an API call

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: Converting object to an encodable object failed: Instance of 'PaymentStatus'
```

The initialisation code for the above section is given as below

```
  double amount,
  double discount,
  String coupon,
  double total,
  String transactionCode,
  PaymentStatus paymentStatus,
  PaymentMode paymentMode,
  PaymentType paymentType,
  int node,
  int user
```

This seems to be enum. But still some issue with JSON encode.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should probably try to covert the enum to string & hope the issue will get solved.

```
paymentStatus = PaymentStatus.something.toString();
```